# Is the n-th odd prime, which has 2 as nonresidue, polynomially bounded by n * ln(n)?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, quadratic-residues

We already know the $p_{n}$ prime is asymptotic with $n \times \ln (n)$. We already know from this [book](https://www.math.brown.edu/~jhs/Frint4thChapter21.pdf), the odd primes which have 2 as nonresidue are congruent 3 or 5 modulo 8. Is the odd prime $q_{n}$, which has 2 as nonresidue, polynomially bounded by $n \times \ln (n)$ or is asymptotic with another function?

Comment: See the [Prime number theorem for arithmetic progressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Prime_number_theorem_for_arithmetic_progressions)